# Navgroup popping windows titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-alloy

```
Alloy.Globals.navGroup.close(currentWindow);

Ti.API.info('Current Controller: ' + currentWindow);
Ti.API.info('Selected Controller: ' + e.row.name);
currentWindow = e.row.name;

alert(currentWindow);
// get the detail controller and window references
var controller = Alloy.createController(e.row.controller, {
    title : e.row.titleValue,
    name : e.row.name,
    isFlyout : true,
    leftMenuVis : $.menuview
});

var newWindow = controller.getView();
//opens option 1 (menu items) window.
Alloy.Globals.navGroup.openWindow(newWindow, {
    animated : true
});
Alloy.Globals.navGroup.window = newWindow;
```

Here is my code, when a menu item in the base flyout is clicked. It should close the window then the new window should be replaced.

However the problem I am having, if I close the previous window, the new window does not appear on screen.

Comment: What version of Titanium / Alloy are you using? NavigationGroup has been removed from Titanium SDK since version 3.2.0. You should use NavigationWindow instead.

Answer (score 0):

I run couple of tests with [`NavigationWindow`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow) and it's possible to close previous window when you are opening new one:

**index.js**

```
$.button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var firstController = Alloy.createController('test');
    var firstView = firstController.getView();
    $.index.openWindow(firstView);

    var secondController = Alloy.createController('test');
    var secondView = secondController.getView();
    $.index.openWindow(secondView);

    secondView.addEventListener('postlayout', function(){
        $.index.closeWindow(firstView);
    });
});

$.index.open();
```

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <NavigationWindow>
        <Window>
            <Button id="button" title="Switch" />
        </Window>
    </NavigationWindow>
</Alloy>
```

However, you can't overwrite or close window, which is root window in NavigationWindow. If you want to changed that you should just create new NavigationWindow with proper Window object:

**index.js**

```
$.button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Alloy.createController('main');
    $.index.close();
});

$.index.open();
```

**main.js**

```
$.button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Alloy.createController('index');
    $.main.close();
});

$.main.open();
```

Comment: Is there a way where I can find out what windows are in the stack? and when you close a window does the controller get closed as well.

Comment: You have to create your own array with Windows and update it on open/close. Controller is removed from memory by GC when all references to it are nulled. Closing view should be enough but it's good to double check with Xcode instruments.